# End of file is reached before the image could be parsed

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3

Can anyone tell me why...
`<img src="@Url.Action("Index", "ReturnImage", @Model.GUID) alt="Doorstep signature" style="width:290px;height:290px;"/>`

is flagging an error with the initial

```
'<'

    End of file was reached before the 'img' tag could be parsed. Elements inside markup blocks must be complete. 
    They must either be self-closing("<br />") or have matching end tags ("<p>Hello</p>". 
    If you intended to display a "<" character, use the "&lt;" HTML entity.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the runtime can't process the conflicting quote marks.  For src it is seeing `"@Url.Action("`

Change this to something like:

```
<img src='@Url.Action("Index", "ReturnImage", @Model.GUID)' alt="Doorstep signature" style="width:290px;height:290px;"/>
```